# NoMethodError on heroku precompile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
Counting objects: 159, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (145/145), done.
Writing objects: 100% (159/159), 7.13 MiB | 809.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 159 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.6
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 1.2.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.6
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.11.1
remote:        Installing rainbow 2.0.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing turf 0.0.5
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing jquery-livetype-rails 0.2.0
remote:        Installing pg 0.19.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing puma 3.6.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing wicked_pdf 1.1.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.4
remote:        Installing frontend-generators 0.1.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.7
remote:        Installing activemodel 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.6.1
remote:        Installing activejob 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing activerecord 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.1
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing actionview 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing actionpack 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing actionmailer 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing actioncable 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing railties 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Installing rails 5.0.0.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing typedjs-rails 1.0.4
remote:        Installing animate-rails 1.0.10
remote:        Installing typing 0.1.3
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Installing jquery-typewriter-rails 0.9.5
remote:        Bundle complete! 22 Gemfile dependencies, 62 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (25.55s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:01.021767 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/manifest-33352b8934bf8fd897922446e0806fababfcb99ba49f1321020391ab617a51ea.js
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:01.022366 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/manifest-33352b8934bf8fd897922446e0806fababfcb99ba49f1321020391ab617a51ea.js.gz
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.933530 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/manifest-10e6fb3bdd56851bb6f7a904647ca2f752e8b9f8545b8cad2530792f1f7ecc47.css
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.933737 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/manifest-10e6fb3bdd56851bb6f7a904647ca2f752e8b9f8545b8cad2530792f1f7ecc47.css.gz
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.935106 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/header-012975bc0328ef43ba0535ef270cde7d9daa108dd20a707e487d278959bcb5f9.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.939720 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/1-90b6399bec2619f663bec20601c14d65e2a6517ea8c00d23f0109be2c66feb33.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.943213 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/2-f830fdfc221bfc636bdb03ba3a40b6579ae8e46579cceae498147be147b7d880.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.946272 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/3-b587cdabd57a6825115f40551465bbd12b9812906a2e8a0c8fe5e30b3d468ecf.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.949220 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/4-83a1cb38cfbcc72ebb605b9e2d2384a6ef1503095335827522a976366ed316f2.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.952232 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/5-2f8eb3527b4c09cca0cffd856266c8da6708565a318485352b0c76c0e62c2720.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.955245 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/6-c16202c5945d6c5dc2631437188e35cd309b65fb4a2dc639b8d06023fba00a6b.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:02.971194 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/housearch-ecf5b0c7ad417fff305728938156a034cd90cb527b8430432613c29c6873f2c0.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:03.002762 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/ironlibrary-810ff69cf6c9d8ab566cc6521711d72fd1f71a63ede42a4384e0ea488064bdd8.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:03.008083 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/readit-2c2e1a8fd7de59d3bdf58b34c202cc9aa41e67e2c47242b2f5fa1d30b50abee6.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:03.012562 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/creative/portfolio/tweeter-dc146d47d5957d78630e765cd9d02dc0aef61660897b742bb1380e06a17f60d6.jpg
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:03.015064 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/maaz-resume-93aec4cad7ef9b55525bfb4d112846601559868edab92a607e247bc13bb08e54.pdf
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:06.060064 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/application-5891f1f4ff41fefea08e44a43db3ee6fa6cd8e6fa0e3198263581408bf56fe6c.js
remote:        I, [2016-12-15T06:58:06.060279 #1186]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/public/assets/application-5891f1f4ff41fefea08e44a43db3ee6fa6cd8e6fa0e3198263581408bf56fe6c.js.gz
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in `sprockets_context'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:137:in `asset_url'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:143:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:58:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:397:in `visit_prop'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:433:in `block in visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:431:in `visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_b39dc487e6a60a3e19d6c29892dc89cb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to mazeem.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/mazeem.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mazeem.git'
```

Not sure what i need to correct, it works perfectly fine locally, i looked at other posts and made the correct changes but still nothing. my *application.css* file has been changed to *application.css.scss*

Comment: what did you see in `heroku logs` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be an error in your scss files. You should test assets' precompile on the local machine.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Too read this thread with same error:
[rake assets:precompile undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313612/rake-assetsprecompile-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass)