# Heroku Production - ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `directory' for #<Sprockets::Manifest:number>)

Tags: heroku, browserify, sprockets, react-rails

We have a react-rails app. Unfortunately, the app works on local development but not when deployed to heroku. When going to our default path on the app, we get the following error:
`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'directory' for #<Sprockets::Manifest:0x007fef13200aa8>)`

We've figured out that it happens at this line in our view: 
`<%= react_component('NavBar', {}, {prerender: true}) %>`

A few things about our app:

- It uses browserify to compile our js.jsx.
- We precompile using `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` after deleting the public/assets folder.
- Works locally with both `rails s` and `foreman start`
- We are using boostrap-sprockets. Even when removed, we still have this issue.

Here is our npm dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
   "browserify": "^10.2.4",
   "browserify-incremental": "^1.5.0",
   "classnames": "^2.2.3",
   "reactify": "^1.1.0"
}
```

Here is our Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
    gem 'rails-api'
    gem 'spring', :group => :development
    gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0.rc1'
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'puma'
    gem 'twitter'
    gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.0'
    gem 'browserify-rails', '~> 0.9.1'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.4'
    gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
    group :test  do
      gem 'rspec-rails'
      gem 'pry'
      gem 'faker'
      gem 'webmock'
    end
    group :development, :test do
      gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    end
    group :production do
      gem 'uglifier'
      gem 'rails_12factor'
      gem 'rspec'
    end
    ruby '2.2.4'
```

We would appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution from hours of searching on StackOverflow and github issues seems to be to remove

```
//= require react_ujs
```

from your application.js in your assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue just today and followed the suggestions in: https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/443#issuecomment-180544359. I was still running into an error so for now I modified my heroku configurations (config/environments/staging.rb & config/environments/production.rb) to use

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

for now and server-side rendering worked fine. The react-rails folks said they have a pull request completed to fix this issue but I dont think it has been released yet.

Comment: For others coming across this potential solution to their issues, turning on live compilation is not recommended as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compile-set-to-true-in-production

Answer (score 0):

Potentially relevant: [rake assets:precompile undefined method directory? for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041393/rake-assetsprecompile-undefined-method-directory-for-nilnilclass)

This is an error that occurs when the Rails asset compiler (Sprockets) cannot find a directory that you've specified as the location of an asset for your project. My suggestion is to make sure that all your assets are being successfully deployed to heroku, and then check that your paths are set up correctly when you reference assets in your project for inclusion in a page.

Also see [Eric C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733801/771275) pertaining to React-Rails specifically.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in `react-rails` 1.6.0 which should be fixed in 1.6.1

Here's the patch:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/pull/478

If the latest version doesn't work for you, please open an issue on the react-rails repo!